# Counting conditional jumps

Tags: linux, assembly, branch, conditional-statements, perf

I have kind of a noob'ish question. I am totally new to Linux.

I would like to count the number of conditional jumps (i.e. the number of if()s, while()s etc taken by a program) taken by a program.

I was told I could do this with perf and I read up on that but I am totally lost.

Could anyone tell me how do I go about it? So for instance I have a C++ program that is something like:

```
...some code...
if(a=5)
  x=3;
else
  x=5;
...some code...
```

and supposed this code is compiled into a file called tmp.

I tried issuing the following:

```
perf stat ./tmp
```

but the number of branches I get are different each time.

Am I doing something wrong?

EDIT: I should mention that I am assuming I have no source code available. So I am looking at binaries.

Comment: do you want to count what the high level source codes opinion of this is or the generated machine code (which will be a different answer)?  Recursively following execution paths through machine code is not difficult, only a fraction of a dissembler is needed.

Comment: I am looking at counting the jumps in generated machine code i.e. the binaries. I didn't get your whole point though. The number of conditionals should be the same in both cases right?

Comment: I gotta ask: When is this information relevant/interesting?

Comment: Its part of some idea I have and I'm trying to see if it works before I invest more time and effort.

Answer (score 0):

Its logical that the number of branches change each time you run the program since the code executed before the `main` function may do different things each times. (example: `perf stat true` will report each times a different number of branches).

The interesting thing with `perf stat` is the number of branch-misses, that have a negative impact on the program execution speed (you wont see it unless you run a program that have 100% of branch-misses for a long time, so its not a *really* important negative impact).

Comment: Ah thanks, but I am interested in conditional branches... which should always correspond to the number of branches (if()s, whiles()s...) in the program. turns out I can do it by using the hardware Event Number+Umask for conditional branch instructions as an argument to perf stat! for example in my case (on a Core2 Duo system) becomes:
   perf stat -e branches,r8b00 your_program

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found out a solution, but forgot to post it here. 
Counting branches should always correspond to the number of branches (if()s, whiles()s...) in the program. turns out I can do it by using the hardware Event Number+Umask (Ref: Intel Manuals for Software Engineers) for conditional branch instructions as an argument to perf stat!

Comment: Achilles, can you show us the full perf command line and your full CPU model? Which event was used and what is the umask.

Comment: @osgx I am guessing it's a bit late, but to help future queries (on a core2Duo system  - don't remember the exact CPU model): `perf stat -e branches,r8b00 your_program`

Comment: was it some event like BR_INST_EXEC.ANY or BR_INST_EXEC.COND? https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/managed/8b/6e/335279_performance_monitoring_events_guide.pdf?ref=hvper.com, and BR_INST_RETIRED.CONDITIONAL & BR_INST_EXEC.ALL_CONDITIONAL for recent cpu cores?

Comment: @osgx It's been a few years, but I think I looked at retired conditional branch instructions (BR_INST_RETIRED.CONDITIONAL)  to build the actual control flow path that was followed by the program in a certain execution.